# incrementing form default values with jquery, not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, html, forms, default-value

When I submit my first form (#modelform) I have a second form (#waldform) appear with a default value defined in its text area. This is done in jquery. This default value comes from a counter that increments each time the #modelform is submitted. These defaut values should be integers but for some reason they are displaying as "1/", "2/" etc (without quotes).

Is there something wrong with how I'm setting the default values in #waldform?

```
var $counter = 0

    $("#modelform").submit(function() {

        $counter =  $counter + 1

        // post the form values via AJAX...
        $.post('/estimate', {name: $("#mymodel").val()}, function(data) {

            $('body').append('<form class="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" id="waldnum" value=' + $counter + '/><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form>');

    });

return false ;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close off the value field

```
<input type="text" id="waldnum" value="' + $counter + '"/>
```

You were missing the " " - which was causing the output to display the rest of the element -> eg 2/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the quotes in your string. Try this..

```
$('body').append('<form class="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" id="waldnum" value="' + $counter + '" /><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form>');
```

Also..

```
$counter++;
```

is a nicer way to do

```
$counter =  $counter + 1
```

Although, they are exactly the same and both work fine